# Powershell adding CR at the end of regex match group

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm gettting a CR between the regex match and the ','. What's going on?

```
$r_date ='ExposeDateTime=([\w /:]{18,23})'   
$v2 = (Select-String -InputObject $_ -Pattern $r_date | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}) + ',';
```

Example of output:

> 9/25/2018 8:45:19 AM[CR],

Original String:

```
ExposeDateTime=9/25/2018 8:45:19 AM
Error=Dap
PostKvp=106
PostMa=400
PostTime=7.2
PostMas=2.88
PostDap=0
```

Comment: Maybe try including `-replace [Environment]::NewLine,""`, or `-replace "\`t|\`n|\`r",""`

Comment: Thanks but I'm able to remove the CR. I just don't understand where it's coming from.

Comment: Without seeing the actual original string doubtful anyone here could tell you...

Comment: I've added the original string. It does have [CR][LF] at the end of each line.

Comment: You are missing the code that's likely the cause of it, which is the code that sets `$_` for use in `Select-String`. You probably have another `ForEach-Object` iterating over the output of `Get-Content` or a `-split` or something. We need to see that.

Comment: How do you fetch the original string, Get-(Child)Item, Get-Content or some another way? I tried to reproduce: I put the original string in a text file and did a Get-Item to pipe it to your code. Worked perfectly

Comment: Can you add some other sample inputs and the outputs you want? Please make sure that the samples contain all the conditions you want checked.

Comment: Move the trailing `+','` **inside** the ForEach. The parentheses force the evaluation (including a CR) and you append to that.

Comment: in case if u have win format ending in original input [Cr][Cn] and use construction like (get-content $file) -split '\n' you will get described result, because split remove [Cn] char but left [Cr]

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$original = @"
ExposeDateTime=9/25/2018 8:45:19 AM
Error=Dap
PostKvp=106
PostMa=400
PostTime=7.2
PostMas=2.88
PostDap=0
"@

$r_date ='ExposeDateTime=([\d\s/:]+(?:(?:A|P)M)?)'   
$v2 = (Select-String -InputObject $original -Pattern $r_date | ForEach-Object {$_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}) -join ','
```

Regex details:

> ```
> ExposeDateTime=    Match the characters “ExposeDateTime=” literally
> (                  Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
>    [\d\s/:]        Match a single character present in the list below
>                    A single digit 0..9
>                    A whitespace character (spaces, tabs, line breaks, etc.)
>                    One of the characters “/:”
>       +            Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
>    (?:             Match the regular expression below
>       (?:          Match the regular expression below
>                    Match either the regular expression below (attempting the next alternative only if this one fails)
>             A      Match the character “A” literally
>          |         Or match regular expression number 2 below (the entire group fails if this one fails to match)
>             P      Match the character “P” literally
>       )
>       M            Match the character “M” literally
>    )?              Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

if your input is a multiline string stored in `$Original`, then this rather simpler regex seems to do the job. [*grin*] it uses a named capture group and the `multiline` regex flag to capture the string **after** `ExposedDateTime=` and **before** the next line ending.

```
$Original -match '(?m)ExposeDateTime=(?<Date>.+)$'
$Matches.Date
```

output ...

```
9/25/2018 8:45:19 AM
```